# arm cortex-m least stack address and SRAM address relationship

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I just read a guide of cortex M3 and M4. The memory map is a little confuse to me. The stack address sounds like start from 0x20007C00. and SRAM start from 0x20000000 to 0x20007C00? But how come microncontroller like STM32F407VGT6 has 192+4KB SRAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement of the stack is entirely up to you and how you program and link your code. Likewise the amount of RAM is entirely SoC dependent.  Here is the general m3 memory map:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0182h/CHDBFJED.html